# How to structure a service that needs multiple repositories?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, repository-pattern

I have a Service that uses 2 repositories and I wanna make unit tests. So for testing I need to have the constructor take interfaces instead of the repository class directly, so I can mock the repositories. But then I can't set their DbContext to the same which will lead to other problems.

Here's the code:

```
public class RolePrivilegeService : IRolePrivilegeService
{
    private readonly RoleReadWriteRepository _roleRepo;
    private readonly PrivilegeReadRepository _privilegeRead;

    public RolePrivilegeService(RoleReadWriteRepository roleWrite, 
        PrivilegeReadRepository privilegeRead)
    {
        _roleRepo = roleWrite;
        _privilegeRead = privilegeRead;

        _roleRepo.Db = _privilegeRead.Db;
    }

    public async Task<int> AssignPrivilege(string roleId, string privilegeId, string companyId)
    {
        var role = await _roleRepo.FindRole(companyId, roleId);
        if(role == null) throw new RoleNotFoundException();

        var privilege = await _privilegeRead.Find(privilegeId);
        if(privilege == null) throw new PrivilegeNotFoundException();

        role.AssignPrivilege(privilege);

        return await _roleRepo.UpdateRole(role);
    }
}
```

*The interfaces and entities are in one project and the service and repositories are in another project.*

Comment: By abstracting away implementation concerns so that they can be mocked. class should depend on abstractions and not concretions.

Comment: I don't understand why injecting repositories interfaces could prohibit mocking DbContext. I guess that your repositories also use constructor injection. If so, there are certainly no reasons against mocking Entity Framework DbContext - just create proper instance before creating repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I guess from the beginning it's not the best solution to give to the service the responsibility to manage the unicity of the context.

Some possible solution (my favorite is the third one)

1)  Use interfaces instead and inject DBContext (Define your strategy here, one DBContext by request if you are in api or whatever...)

2) You can anyway mock a concrete class with NSubstitute or others

3) Improve your design with having one Repository to have a better abstraction of the needed entity (Using an aggregate which is a better abstraction of your transactional boundaries)